# What bean-to-cup machines are available with dual hopper system to allow regular and decaf at the same machine?

Tags: espresso-machine, bean-to-cup

I'm looking to buy an automated coffee machine for our small office setting; maybe 10 cups a day as a perk for our employees.

One thing that I feel we need is the ability to make decaf and caffeinated with the same machine.

This is the cheapest machine I've found that has a dual hopper setup:
[Jura Giga 5 Automatic Coffee Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AKY0BCS).

Are there cheaper ones out there?  At this price point it almost feels like two machines would be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Many single-hopper machines have a little flap, drawer or similar opening where you can add ground coffee for one serving.

If you add one type of beans in the machine’s hopper you can use the second slot for the other.

The fact that the second one takes ground coffee doesn’t mean that half of your coffee drinkers have to use pre-ground, a good grinder should cost way less than a second machine or a dual hopper one. Just decide which group gets to use which setup. While we instinctively might say that the group that drinks more gets the simplest “just push a button” solution, maybe one fraction actually likes the “ritual” of the separate grinder.

---

Update:

As per request, I checked for examples.

This is the machine at my office: A BOSCH VeroCafe, you can see the opened chute.
[image: Bosch machine]

The JURA machines I checked (randomly on the [website](https://jura.com)) all feature “powder recognition for additional ground coffee variety”.

For SAECO I checked the (comparatively cheap) Incanto model and yes, this also has the [“powder option”](https://www.usa.philips.com/c-p/HD8911_47/incanto-super-automatic-espresso-machine) feature.

Comment: thanks so much. Can you point out a machine that has that?  I'm just curious how it's advertised.

Comment: I just checked with the Jura website (just because that’s what you showed in your question) and the term for them seems to be “Powder recognition for additional ground coffee variety”. But of course a seller like amazon won’t bother with that level of detail in the product description... ;-) IIRC, the Bosch machine at the office has the feature as well.

Comment: The low-end Delonghi machines all have this option too, for instance https://www.beantocupcoffeemachines.net/reviews/delonghi/magnifica-esam4200/